# Setting up xorg.conf metamodes for nvidia letterboxing

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, resolution

I'm currently trying to configure my `xorg.conf` to letterbox screen resolutions smaller than the native resolution of my display (`1680x1050`) so that I can play older games full screen without distortion. I've found that there is a way to do this, which involves adding metamodes to `xorg.conf`, but documentation is minimal so I'm a little scared to start mucking with `xorg.conf` without further input. For the sake of example, say I have a game which runs at a native resolution of `1024x768`. What would I add in order to center and letterbox that?

Here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And here are a couple links which might come in handy:

A similar question: http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=184968

Documentation: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/302.17/README/configtwinview.html#metamodes

Thanks!